# How to alert a bus driver to stop without pushing the stop button

Tags: public-transport, london, buses

In London on red buses, is it ok if you are standing at the front of the bus to say “Can you stop at the next stop please”, instead of pushing yourself through the bus to press the stop button?

The reason I am asking is because at the top near the driver it says not to obstruct or distract him.

Is this “distracting”?

What other ways could I alert the driver or do I need to press the Stop button?

Comment: I don't understand the reason for this question. Just push the stop button.

Comment: @MJeffryes if i am at the front and the bus is packed i don't want to push through a ton of people

Comment: I too am struggling to understand the reason for this question. On every U.K. bus I’ve ever been on there’s always been a stop button to press close to the front of the bus and at least 4 other buttons strategically placed throughout both levels. It’s far better to push the button than ask the driver - there’s also usually a sign saying not to talk to the driver while the bus is moving. If you can’t reach the button you can ask someone to press it for you

Comment: @Traveller the bus i go on the stop button is quite a bit back

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the situation too. If it's so packed that you can't get to the button, you'd have to shout pretty loud for the driver to hear (and then they might interpret it as an emergency rather than a request to stop). Easier to ask someone else to press it!

Comment: If you get near or stand near the driver cabin, the driver will ask you to get back as he(she) cannot view the mirrors.

Comment: @DumbCoder It's fairly likely the sign that says not to distract the driver also says something like "do not stand forward of this notice".

Comment: I can think of a couple locations on a bus where this question makes sense _in practice_. One is where you are not meant to stand on (to the left of the driver), and the other (on the middle of the corridor in a packed double decker, squished near the wall) is awkward. In the first case, chances are you won't miss your stop as someone else would have pressed the stop button - you just need to ask the driver to let you off via the front when it is stationary (they usually keep it shut to prevent more people going on). In the second case, do as @HankyPanky suggested works charm.

Comment: Is it really that confusing to imagine a situation where you can't physically reach the button but can talk to the driver? Yeesh.

Comment: @AzorAhai I find it confusing because, when I get on a London bus, as soon as I've scanned my Oyster card I move into the interior of the bus, away from the driver. That is important to allow room for anyone behind me to get on the bus, and to avoid distracting the driver or obstructing their view once the bus starts moving. I have never been in a situation in which I could neither reach a stop button nor get another passenger to press it for me.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I have quite frequently gotten on buses (not in London) where there is no room to move further into the bus. It must be nice that your buses don't get that full. My point wasn't that you couldn't ask someone else to press it for you (and indeed, that's the answer, instead of bothering the driver), but that I'm baffled no one can picture a scenario where they can't reach a button but can yell loud enough for the driver to hear.

Comment: @AzorAhai We don't yell at our drivers in this country, nor do we crowd around the area where they sit and drive. Both are serious safety problems.

Comment: I don't know what the rules are in the UK, but in the Netherlands it's illegal to talk to the driver.

Comment: @Mast I'm not sure that there are specific laws in the UK but there's usually a sign just behind the entrance vestibule saying that you shouldn't stand farther forward than the sign and that, while the bus is moving, you shouldn't speak to or distract the driver without good reason.

Comment: Do London busses make a fairly loud sound when one pushes the stop button? And do drivers skip stops if nobody pushes the button and nobody is waiting at the stop? If so, a possible explanation for OP's rationale is their fear to annoy other travellers if OP doesn't know if the driver would stop anyway or not, and prefer more discreet solutions like talking privately to the driver. I personally feel more comfortable to push the stop button if it only lights.

Comment: @Mast It might be illegal, but I've seen drivers chatting to passengers often. Have you ever seen that rule enforced?

Comment: @Lightness okay, fine "speak loudly enough to hear."

Comment: @AzorAhai You shouldn't be distracting the driver. And there is no need to, because there is a button that serves the purpose of letting them know you want to get off, in a manner that is consistent and non-distracting. This is the system designed for the purpose, and the system that you should use. Self-explanatory!

Comment: @RHA It's barely enforced, but to answer your question, yes, I've seen it happen.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh my goodness, I understand that! The answer to the question is to ask someone else, not to bother the driver. I'm not endorsing yelling at the driver. I'm just very impressed that London buses are well-engineered enough that you are never ever too far from a button!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The **stop button** is exactly there to ask the driver to stop at the next stop. If you can't get to a button, please politely request someone and they will be happy to press it for you.

Here is some interesting insight that could help you. The following information comes from the [Big Red Book](http://www.transportforall.org.uk/news/bus-drivers-big-red-book), which is the official instructions guide for TFL Bus drivers.

> **As your bus reaches the stop…**
>
> Look and listen out for passengers intending to get off. Ideally they
>   will let you know they wish to get off by ringing the bell but be
>   prepared to stop in case they do not.
>
> If in doubt, stop. If you are sure no one wants to get on or off you
>   can keep going.

So, make it look like you want to get off on this stop and chances are that you will be spotted by the driver even without having pressed the button during such busy rides.

If that doesn't work;  ***Next stop, please*** doesn't sound like a distraction.

Comment: On most of the London fleet, the button will also light a "bus stopping" indicator sign visible to the driver, which avoids uncertainty as to whether the driver has heard you.

Comment: Asking the driver will not light this light.

Comment: It's not pressing the stop button that the questioner refers to being possibly a distraction; it's asking the driver to stop that might be a distruction.

Comment: @md2perpe you're right, answer updated accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

In the meaning of the sign, asking him to make a stop is not a distraction.   The sign is referring to irrelevant talk, particularly that requiring thinking: means don't ask for the time, ask his opinion on Brexit, union organize, etc.

Think of it like ["Sterile Cockpit" for pilots](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2000/june/pilot/the-sterile-cockpit), or what [US NTSB says about focus on the driving task](https://www.ntsb.gov/safety/mwl/Pages/mwl1_2015.aspx).  Asking if the Dreamliner is fun to fly is not appropriate in sterile cockpit, but very correct to ask about a flaps setting that looks funny.  Listening to a roiling political show is a distraction, but Siri saying "turn left 500 feet" is on-task.

**Calling for a stop is definitely acceptable**, as it is on-task and brief.

You can also say "I need Bristol Road".

Comment: If it's a sterile cockpit, and they have a don't-freaking-talk-to-me persona going, I push the button. If they're having a conversation with someone anyway, I might ask - especially if there's only like 3 people on the bus. If you're the one guy on the bus and you push the button, that's kinda rude IMO. On an empty bus I always say thanks and exit the front.

Comment: Saying *"next stop please"* in a clear voice also works wonders.

Answer (score 11):

If you can't easily reach a stop button and can't get somebody else to press one for you, it's perfectly reasonable to verbally ask the driver to stop. Indeed, when I was a child, thirty years ago, it was completely normal to just walk to the front of the bus and say "Next stop, please" rather than pressing the button. That always felt more polite than pressing the button.  Today, everyone seems to just press the button.

However, if you have to raise your voice to get this request heard, it's almost certainly inappropriate. Yelling at the driver will certainly distract them from driving and their first thought will be that something is seriously wrong. You shouldn't do that. Worst case is that you'll miss your stop but stops are usually pretty frequent so having to walk back a stop isn't going to be the end of the world.

It would be better to be more prepared. As you get within a couple of stops of where you want to alight, you should be able to manoeuvre yourself within reach of a button. As people get off at the stops before yours, people are moving around the bus anyway, which gives you an opportunity.

Comment: You walked to the front of a *London* bus? When the exit doors are in the middle? Getting off at the front is difficult because of those who want to get on and helps no-one.

Comment: @AndrewLeach The word "London" appears where in my answer?

Comment: It's the second word in the question, and sets its parameters.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'm pretty sure my answer applies to every bus in the UK. In particular, the first sentence of the question explicitly says that the asker is already at the front of the bus.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Also note the “…walked to the front…” anecdote is from 30 years ago; I can vouch that getting off at the front door was completely normal in London at that date (as was the rest of what David Richerby describes).

Comment: In which case it's neither relevant nor helpful *now*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach there is no single type of London bus. On less-used routes that don't go into the centre there are smaller single-decker buses with only one set of doors at the front, and you can stay at the front and verbally request the next stop if you like.

Comment: @AndrewLeach and it’s certainly still helpful to the rest of the U.K.!

Comment: @AndrewLeach Please read my answer more carefully. The second and third sentences are an anecdote relating to my childhood (which, for the record, was not in London). The rest of my answer, which talks about how to use buses today, applies to buses anywhere in the UK. I don't understand why you're focusing on that one part of my answer, to the exclusion of all else.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this “distracting”?

**YES.**  Heavens, yes!  The driver is alerted primarily by the **audible chime** so as to not distract their eyes.

Though they're likely trained to ignore passengers, there's still an internal push to focus on a person demanding attention.

> What other ways could I alert the drive or do I need to press the Stop button?

You can **pull the cord** if the bus is also equipped with one.

If the bus is very crowded, hollering "Next Stop" **well outside the drivers field of vision** isn't the worst thing in the world, but still, push the button or pull the cord.

Comment: Feedback (did not downvote): The statement "You can pull the cord if the bus is also equipped with one." is true (as in the implication itself is valid), but not useful, in the sense that one will struggle to find a London bus that comes with a cord. Happy to be corrected though!

Comment: Also, please don't pull the cord on many old trains, this is normally the emergency stop cord, and not what you want to be pulling at all ;)

Comment: @B.Liu Finding a bus with a cord is easy if you know where to look. As well as the LT Museum, although you won't get very far on buses there, there's [Route 15H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Buses_route_15_(Heritage)).

Comment: @AndrewLeach That is very true indeed. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2):

> The reason I am asking is because at the top near the driver it says not to obstruct or distract him. […]
>   Is this “distracting”?

*This is a bit quite funny confusion.*

No, it isn’t. A sign asking to not distract a bus driver means you should not try to discuss with a driver a recent football game nor discuss it loudly by phone with your friend while sitting near the driver and not to obstruct means avoid putting your snowboards in a way that reduces driver’s visibility.

A stop (bell) button is actually designed to avoid engaging a (possibly distracting) conversation with a bus driver just to say a bus should stop on the next bus stop.

Drivers expect that signal and it is less distracting than trying to ask a driver politely in a few words.

**Please note**

Also, remember to ring the stop button (or pull the cord) slightly before approaching the bus stop as the bus driver need some time to respond and slow down a bus safely, if you call the button when a bus is already passing a bus top it might be too late for a safe stop and a driver might skip it (not being happy about your late response.)

**P.S.**

*Probably a bus operating company should update that sign to be more clear and avoid such confusions by adding something likeL “press a stop button when approaching a bus stop you want to exit.”*

Comment: There is no need at all to write an essay on a sign by the stop button. Come on, it's obvious how to use it. Nobody has any difficulty understanding what those buttons are for. The only reason this question exists is to deal with the case where one is on a crowded bus and can't reach one of the buttons.

Comment: Some people for an example with OCD might have difficulties with understanding contradicting signs. There once was an intreating study that showed that written signs affect people reception of the reality, and triggered a discussion in the linguistic world if a surrounding environment forms a vocabulary or the opposite. And according to [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/08ac/3898b4b8b700057bbf02d65bdc16a8024651.pdf) interesting study a wording for a sign like “Exit another way” will be less encouraging subconsciously for suicide rather than “No exit” sign.